# How to invoke private method in Gosu

Tags: reflection, gosu, guidewire

I am trying to call a private method from gosu scratchpad using invoke() method.But i am not able to access that private method.
Can any one tell me the best way to invoke private methods in GOSU Language.Here is the code

```
try{
    var clazz = java.lang.Class.forName(ClaimSearchCriteriaImpl)
    var method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("generateSimpleActiveClaimViewQuery", null)
       method.setAccessible(true)
    var ss =   method.invoke(clazz, null)as ClaimSearchCriteriaImpl
       print("Result.."+ss)
} catch(exception){
        print("***********"+exception)
}
```

When i try to execute this code i am getting the following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class program_.__Program__505 can not access a member of class com.guidewire.cc.domain.claim.impl.ClaimSearchCriteriaImpl with modifiers "private"
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:105)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.slowCheckMemberAccess(AccessibleObject.java:261)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:253)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
    at program_.__Program__505.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at gw.internal.gosu.parser.GosuProgram.runProgram(GosuProgram.java:421)
    at gw.internal.gosu.parser.GosuProgram.evaluate(GosuProgram.java:253)
    at gw.internal.gosu.parser.GosuProgram_Proxy.evaluate(gw.internal.gosu.parser.GosuProgram_Proxy:2)
    at gw.internal.gosu.parser.ExecutionEnvironment$1.evaluate(ExecutionEnvironment.java:543)
    at gw.internal.gosu.parser.ExecutionEnvironment$1.runScript(ExecutionEnvironment.java:523)
    at gw.internal.gosu.parser.ExecutionEnvironment$1.run(ExecutionEnvironment.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: Isn't the whole point of the 'private' keyword to disallow other classes or objects from using methods with that modifier? This seems to me that the application is working as designed.

Comment: did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

The solution by @Shivanandam Sirmarigari actually works now, but there are a few issues.

1st as already mentioned, you need an instance of on object to run on, from the documentation of Method.invoke

> /** @param obj  the object the underlying method is invoked from */
>
> > public Object invoke(Object obj, Object... args)

2nd the ClaimSearchCriteriaImpl actually doesn't have a default constructor, so you need to use something like

```
var obj = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor({ConstructorArgType}).newInstance({argTypeObj})
```

3rd your argTypeObj (possibly obj itself) might actually need a transaction to be created.

Answer (score -1):

**Try this code.. u did't Instantiated **

```
 try{
var clazz = java.lang.Class.forName(ClaimSearchCriteriaImpl)
var method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("generateSimpleActiveClaimViewQuery", null)
Object obj= clazz.newInstance();
   method.setAccessible(true)
var ss =   method.invoke(obj, null)as ClaimSearchCriteriaImpl
   print("Result.."+ss)
} catch(exception){
        print("***********"+exception)
}
```